# How return total distinct user in last 30 days dateCreated

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

There are lots of audit documents in my database like below

```
<Record>
  <objectType>Audit</objectType>
  <dateCreated>2017-04-07T03:51:56.231-04:00</dateCreated>
  <createdBy>first user</createdBy>
</Record>
```

How can I get total number of user(createdBy) who created audit file in last 30 days? There are some audit files in which createdBy same so we require distinct value count.

I tried the query below:

```
let $query := cts:values(cts:element-reference(fn:QName($NS, "createdBy")))
return fn:count($query)
```

But how can I use condition `dateCreated>30` or `cts:range-query` inside `cts:values`.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

(I have set up element range index for createdBy and dateCreated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the constraining range query as the third argument to cts:count-aggregate() - something along the following lines should work:

```
let $index := fn:QName($NS, "dateCreated")
let $count := cts:count-aggregate(
    cts:element-reference($index),
    (),
    cts:element-range-query($index, ">",
        fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D")
        )
    )
```

That should give you the total number of dateCreated values for the past 30 days.

For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:count-aggregate

Comment: Thanks @ehennum for quick response.